# External Monitor and HP Elitebook 840 G5

Tags: display

Installed Elementary OS Hera on a HP Elitebook 840 G5. The OS is fast, stable and responsive.

When plugging in a external monitor to the HDMI port, the monitor itself (an LG 27UD58) recognizes that it has been plugged into a source, but the latptop does not.

When I go to Displays and ask it to identify the displays that it is aware of, it sees the laptop's built-in LCD, but not the external LG.

Update: I'm going to leave this open as the HP Elitebook 840 G5 does not recognize the LG27UD58 monitor, but does recognize other external displays, including other UHD displays, using the HDMI port on the right side of the laptop.

Comment: Does your laptop have multiple video adapters? What is the output of `lspci | grep VGA`?

Comment: Vlad, it looks like it is the specific monitor I was connecting with. Since trying that first monitor, I tried two others, including a Samsung UHD display and they all worked without a hitch (using the HDMI port on the right side of the laptop).